# What do we suffix an interface that always vends the same object (ie., a singleton class)?

Tags: java, singleton, naming-conventions

We suffix "Factory" when the class/interface is used to create numerous objects. What do we suffix an interface that always vends the same object everytime.

If I still use the word factory, am I not overloading the real meaning of Factory, inspite the class always vends the same thing.

(I am new to Business Applications Development)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Naming convention for objects in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345344/naming-convention-for-objects-in-java)

Comment: It is all on conventions and namings.. There is nothing people can do here with it to help you. Read the naming conventions in java and coding standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `*Singleton` with `getInstance` method? For example, `CustomerDatabaseSingleton` with `getInstance` method that returns the single, global instance of `CustomerDatabaseSingleton`.